# Randomising select list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I am a bit stuck with a problem, so I would appreciate any help. I need to randomise the list items in a simple drop down list. I know there are already posts here dealing with this and I tried other solutions also posted here, but they didn`t bring in the wished result.

I have a simple drop down list such as the following:

```
 <select>
      <option value="">Default</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
 </select>
```

I need a different sorting of list items, everytime a user clicks on the dropdown - but I don`t want to set the value of that list (!).

So I basically want a random sort of shown list items, everytime the user the user clicks on the dropdown. The dropdown has a default mode when the page is loaded. The user clicks on the dropdown, the list of item opens - but every time in a different random order -, then the user selects an item from that list.

What would be the easiest way to do that?
Sorry,if this might sound trivial, but I´ve tried already different approaches and they didn`t worked as expected. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Put your data in an array. Randomize the array positions. Use JavaScript to generate your select list.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```js
function shuffle() {
var list = document.getElementById('mySelect');   
var items = list.childNodes;
var itemsArr = [];
for (var i in items) {
    if (items[i].nodeType == 1) { 
 itemsArr.push(items[i]);
    }
}

itemsArr.splice(0, 1); // remove the Default element from the array before sorting
itemsArr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return Math.random() > Math.random() ? 1 : -1;
});
var n=0; // count the number of default element in list to avoid adding more tha one
 //Append the Default element in the beginning of the list
for (i = 0; i<=list.length - 1; i++) {
    if (list.options[i].text=="Default") {
 n++;
    }
}
if(n==0){
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "Default";
    list.add(option);
}
for (i = 0; i < itemsArr.length; ++i) {
    list.appendChild(itemsArr[i]);
}
}
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" onblur="shuffle();">
  <option value="">Default</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/m65qxq82/)

Comment: Thank you very much for these helpful additions so far - there`s one additional requirement to this: The default option of the select list should always be selected - no problem so far -, but it also should never go into the array and randomised. So, the default option is the option the user sees when he gets on the page. It always stays on top of the opened select list; only the items below change randomly their order. What would be the best way to do that? Any idea would be very appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the edit - I tried it, but the default select list element also "wanders" throught the list - which is not suppose to happen. It should always stick in first position, just the elements below should change randomly.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what this code do, [see the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/m65qxq82/)